# Re-Map an array of Object based on sort order of a property

Tags: javascript, sorting, dictionary

Let's see I have a data in following structure

```
[
    {
        "Id": "xyz7",
        "CurrentRow": 0,
        "ReportTime": "2022-07-18T09:00:00+00:00",
        "ExitTime": null,
        "DateField": "2022-07-18"
    },
    {
        "Id": "xyz8",
        "CurrentRow": 1,
        "ReportTime": "2022-07-18T08:00:00+00:00",
        "ExitTime": null,
        "DateField": "2022-07-18"
    },
    {
        "Id": "wxyz0",
        "CurrentRow": 0,
        "ReportTime": "2022-07-19T00:00:00+00:00",
        "ExitTime": null,
        "DateField": "2022-07-19"
    },
    {
        "Id": "wxyz1",
        "CurrentRow": 1,
        "ReportTime": "2022-07-19T00:00:00+00:00",
        "ExitTime": null
        "DateField": "2022-07-19"
    }
]
```

If I have to say sort the structure based on ReportTime of Date : 2022-07-18, that will change the CurrentRow of entries for DateField 2022-07-18 as
0 to 1 (as it will now belong to 1st Index) and for 2nd entry 1 - 0.

In addition, the CurrentRow of other entries (for other date shall also be adapted if they were same as that of day being sorted.)

In order to achieve this my implementation goes like,

I convert the structure to a two dimensional array based on CurrentRow.

Index in dimension 1, represents the CurrentRow.
The element of array will be an array of specific data entry like `[entry_for_date_18,entry_for_date_19]` (Kind of spread sheet with date as columns and CurrentRow as rows.

And then in order to sort, I pick all the entries for a particular date, sort it, and collect it with the original CurrentRow. (Pass 1).

Then I go and update the CurrentRow of original array, using the index (pass 2).

e.g pseudo code:

```
 for(let i=0;i<sortedDayArray.length;i++){
   findByInOriginalArray(sortedDayArray[i].CurrentRow).updateCurrentRowTo(i)
  }
```

Was wondering if there is a better or more efficient way to do that, using map ?

Comment: Can you clarify?  Is it that you'd like to sort on the date and use the currentRow prop as a secondary sort?  Or you'd like to sort on date and then update currentRow prop to == new position?  Maybe explain what you hope updateCurrentRow would do?

Comment: FWIW on mobile all I see are square and curly braces. Maybe dedent a little bit; code on its side isn’t a graph of how awesome it is.

Comment: @DaveNewton - de-dented, still bewildering

Comment: @danh No. Actually consider it like a spreadsheet where each column has a time. Now if I sort column 1 (based on time) then while moving rows, data of column 2 shall also go along

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got your question: you want to sort your array based on `ReportTime`, then re-arrange `CurrentRow` based on its position in `DateField` and this is the data you are expecting:

```js
[
  {
    Id: 'xyz8',
    CurrentRow: 0,
    ReportTime: '2022-07-18T08:00:00+00:00',
    ExitTime: null,
    DateField: '2022-07-18'
  },
  {
    Id: 'xyz7',
    CurrentRow: 1,
    ReportTime: '2022-07-18T09:00:00+00:00',
    ExitTime: null,
    DateField: '2022-07-18'
  },
  {
    Id: 'wxyz0',
    CurrentRow: 0,
    ReportTime: '2022-07-19T00:00:00+00:00',
    ExitTime: null,
    DateField: '2022-07-19'
  },
  {
    Id: 'wxyz1',
    CurrentRow: 1,
    ReportTime: '2022-07-19T00:00:00+00:00',
    ExitTime: null,
    DateField: '2022-07-19'
  }
]
```

this is the code I came up with:

```js
var tempRow = 0;
var tempDate = ''

YOUR_ARRAY
    .sort((a, b) => (a.ReportTime > b.ReportTime) ? 1 : ((b.ReportTime > a.ReportTime) ? -1 : 0))
    .forEach((row, i) => {
        if (row.DateField != tempDate) {
            tempDate = row.DateField
            tempRow = 0
        }
        row.CurrentRow = tempRow
        tempRow++
    })
```

Comment: Thanks @Rawand but this answer is simple 2D sort. Assume the problem as a spreadsheet where Dates are "Column Headers". Now if user wants to sort based in ReportTime of Date1, then we can't simply use a.ReportTime.  We can't let the column2, get out of sync if user is sorting column 1.

Comment: @Optional but why do other columns get out of sync if you sort by one column, do you want to be able to sort by all columns?

Comment: In spreadsheet, assume two row. Row 1 has column with value C, and X1 and row 2 has column with value A, and X2 then if you sort on basis of column1, why should row 1 become A and and X1. Entire row shall move. So we shall not consider Column 2 in sorting here. I have kinda done that with two (rather 3) passes but was checking on if there are netter way to do that.

Comment: @Optional what I coded for you will move the whole row not just one column, then starts to re-number the CurrentRow based DateField

Comment: `.sort((a, b) => (a.ReportTime > b.ReportTime) ? 1 : ((b.ReportTime > a.ReportTime) ? -1 : 0))` how does it not consider the reportTime of other columns?

Comment: @Optional i believe it is better to check out how `Array.prototype.sort()` works,
check it out here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort